# Where is the Swiftblade PrC and what are its requirements?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, prestige-class, product-identification

I'm a level 1 rogue playing 3.5. My DM said I could multiclass at level 3. I want to multiclass as a swiftblade, but I need more details. What expansion is it part of and what are the requirements?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Take the [tour]. Thank you for your question. Have fun.

Comment: @Scott Undoubtedly the wrong place for a discussion of nomenclature, but could you cite your source for *Taking levels in a prestige class is **not** multiclassing* statement? If that's made clear somewhere, that could have wide-ranging implications.

Comment: Upon further consideration, I believe I am wrong. "Prestige classes offer a new form of multiclassing ... Taking a prestige class does not incur the experience point penalties normally associated with multiclassing." - http://www.d20srd.org/srd/prestigeClasses/prestigeClasses.htm

A new form of multiclassing should probably still be considered multiclassing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Wizards of the Coast Web site archives the Prestige Class column ["The Swiftblade: Haste Personified."](https://web.archive.org/web/20210817000115/http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/prc/20070327) This is the only source for the class.

The linked article details the class's requirements, but, just in case, they are also below.

> **Base Attack Bonus:** +3.
> **Skills:** Concentration 6 ranks, Spellcraft 6 ranks.
> **Spellcasting:** Ability to cast *haste*.
> **Feats:** Dodge, Mobility.
> **Weapon Proficiency:** Must be proficient with at least one martial weapon.
> **Special:** Must have spent the entire previous level using all 3rd level spell slots to exclusively cast *haste*.

These requirements are very difficult to meet for a level 3 character.

Undoubtedly, the fan-made [Swiftblade Handbook](https://web.archive.org/web/20151101015236/http://community.wizards.com:80/forum/previous-editions-character-optimization/threads/1118321) contains answers to many of your other swiftblade questions.

Comment: It is perhaps worth noting that the author of the class has stated that the intent of the special requirement was to use all spell slots of **whatever level you use for *haste*** on *haste*, not 3rd-level specifically. This is relevant because the Celerity domain grants *haste* as a 4th-level spell, and some wanted to access swiftblade as other classes by gaining access to this domain. The author admitted he hadn’t considered this possibility and certainly hadn’t meant to bar that sort of entry.